# Must blockquotes contain paragraphs or must paragraphs contain blockquotes?

Tags: html, blockquote

In HTML5, is it correct to put `blockquotes` inside paragraphs or is the opposite the right way? I mean, logic tells that a `blockquote` may be citing multiple paragraps, doesn't it?

But doesn't `blockquotes` need to contain `q` elements? Could someone explain me the right structure?

EDIT: To add some info. I got this doubt because when trying to implement quotation marks with CSS, they don't appear on `blockquote` but they do on `q` elements. What is the right way to do this?

```css
blockquote, q {
  quotes: "\201C""\201D""\2018""\2019";
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<blockquote>
  <p>Hello!</p>
  <p>Say something!</p>
</blockquote>
<p>He told me <q>Say something!</q>
</p>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [the specifications provided by the W3 group](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element) the `blockquote` is a block level semantic that should contain the entire quote, which can be made up of multiple paragraphs. Because the `blockquote` itself contains one or more paragraphs(or other elements), it doesn't make much sense to put it inside a paragraph. An example, provided by the W3G:

```
<blockquote>
    <p>My favorite book is <cite class="from-source">At Swim-Two-Birds</cite></p>
    <footer>- <cite>Mike[tm]Smith</cite></footer>
</blockquote>
```

As you can see, the example `blockquote` contains text that's inside of `p` elements, but not inside of `q` elements.

[The `q` element is a text level semantic](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-q-element) and it should be used to indicate that part of the text is a quotation. Because the `blockquote` already indicates quotation, marking the text inside with `q`-elements is not necessary. An example, taken from the W3G specification:

```
<p>The man said <q>Things that are impossible just take longer</q>. I disagreed with him.</p>
```

Long story short: if you use a `blockquote` element, put other elements (such as `p` elements) inside of it, but it's not necessary to use `q` elements inside a `blockquote`.

Answer (score 12):

According to the [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) `<p>`s can only contains [Phrasing content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Phrasing_content), which blockquote isn't.

On the other side [blockquote](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blockquote) can contain [Flow content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#Flow_content) which `<p>` is.

So only paragraph inside blockquote is valid, but not the opposite.

Answer (score 5):

`blockquote` is the block-level *replacement* for `q` elements.

If you want to *quote* multiple *paragraphs* so that it looks like a *block*, use `blockquote` and put `p`s inside them.

See [MDN on `blockquote`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/blockquote)

> The HTML `<blockquote>` Element (or HTML Block Quotation Element) indicates that the enclosed text is an extended quotation.

The example has a `<p>` *inside* a `<blockquote>`.

[`<q>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/q) on the other hand says:

> The HTML Quote Element (`<q>`) indicates that the enclosed text is a short inline quotation. This element is intended for short quotations that don’t require paragraph breaks; for long quotations use `<blockquote>` element.

---

Bottom line: the correct usage is:

```
<blockquote>
  <p>Paragraph 1.</p>
  <p>Paragraph 2.</p>
</blockquote>
<p>
  Paragraph 3 with a <q>short quotation</q>.
</p>
```

Comment: That is nice, but what really made me doubt is that, blockquote alone doesn't show quotemarks, I don't know why. I'll update my question.

Comment: @Vandervals It’s not supposed to show quote marks. The default styling is a margin, not quote marks.