# No effect of CSS rule on descendants of <p> tag

Tags: html, css, paragraph

HTML:

```
     <section id="sec1">
      This section has <blockquote> this blockquote, which has <a href="">this link</a>
      </blockquote>
     </section>

     <p id="para1">
      This paragraph has  <blockquote> this blockquote, which has <a href="">this link</a>
      </blockquote>
     </p>
```

CSS:

```
section blockquote a {
  font-weight:bold;
  color:red;

}

p blockquote a {
  font-weight:bold;
  color:green;
}
```

CSS rule related to `<section>` works perfectly but same rule for `<p>` does not.

Here is [codepen](https://codepen.io/imranypatel/pen/oNbxEbQ) to check.

Any guide/reference to understand such behaviors?

Comment: You can't add a blockquote inside a p. blockquote is a flow content element, p only accepts phrasing content. You can check on MDN. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p . If you open your dev tool, you'll see that the p is autoclosing before the blockquote, meaning that your css rule won't target it anymore.

Comment: Tons of useful information on SO : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170760/must-blockquotes-contain-paragraphs-or-must-paragraphs-contain-blockquotes