# Is it ok if a blockquote happens to be in a paragraph <p> tag?

Tags: html, paragraph, blockquote

I've read [*Must blockquotes contain paragraphs or must paragraphs contain blockquotes?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170760/must-blockquotes-contain-paragraphs-or-must-paragraphs-contain-blockquotes), so I see why `blockquote`s can contain `p` elements themselves. However, I feel that this, in principle, shouldn't exclude that a `blockquote` can happen to be in a `p` elements; after all, the `p`s inside the `blockquote` are the paragraphs relative to the quoted text, but why couldn't the quoted text be part of a bigger paragraph of the containing document?

See the following

```html
<p>This is a paragraph</p>

<p> This is another paragraph: with a &lt;blockquote&gt; in it
<blockquote>some long quote</blockquote>
which (notice the lower case <i>w</i>) I write something about here, so it makes sense I'm not starting a new parapgraph, imho.
</p> <!-- this very editor highlights "p>" in red -->
```

Comment: Great, -1 for what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it ok if a blockquote happens to be in a paragraph `<p>` tag?

No.

The start of the blockquote element will implicitly end the p element.

This is why the end tag for the p element is shown is red: There's no matching start tag for it because the element is already closed.

```css
p { background: yellow; }
```

```html
<p>This is a paragraph</p>

<p> This is another paragraph: with a &lt;blockquote&gt; after it
<blockquote>some long quote</blockquote>
and this isn't inside a paragraph as you can tell because the CSS doesn't give it a yellow background
</p> <!-- this very editor highlights "p>" in red -->
```

Comment: Well, the trick of coloring proves your point unequivocally. Now I just wander what in my use case is so "wrong".

Comment: Ask the people who wrote the spec in the '90s.

Comment: By the way, is _The start of the blockquote element will implicitly end the p element_ written somewhere in the standard?

Comment: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-p-element - see the tag omission section for the p element.

Comment: Fantastic, not even a `ul` can be in a `p`. What a silly design from the '90s.

Answer (score -1):

See [the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element) on how `blockquote` is intended. Inside a quote `p` are allowed but not vice versa. You could use a blockquote inside an article or section however.

Having said that. I don't believe any browser out there minds you doing whatever you like. Browsers are like that.

Comment: All browsers mind.

Comment: try this <h2>Lewis Caroll wrote:</h2>
<blockquote>
<p>Twas brillig, and the slithy toves
Did gyre and gimble in the wabe;
All mimsy were the borogoves,
And the mome raths outgrabe.
</p>
<p>
Beware the Jabberwock, my son!
The jaws that bite, the claws that catch!
Beware the Jubjub bird, and shun
The frumious Bandersnatch!
</blockquote>

Comment: Well, Quentin's snippet shows that browsers do care.

Comment: Indeed. <p> within a <blockqoute> works but a new <blockquote> will close a preceding <p> . Perheps one reason is that </ > tags are less important. </li> </td> </tr> </option> to name a few are all redundant and can be omitted as it is clear when they were left out. (<li> implicitly closes the preceding <li>) A clever design from the '20-ties